# Convert Nested Loop to lapply

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am using two loops. In the second loop, I am incrementing value by 1 and then applying filter based on that and converting it to data.matrix so that matrix multiplication can be done in later steps. Is there any way to make it efficient using lapply, expand.grid or any other method?

```
library(dplyr)
xx <- structure(list(Ars_0 = c(1308.56, 5728.84, 2177.82), Ars_1 = c(0, 0, 0), 
                    Ars_2 = c(0, 0, 0), age = c(13, 31, 43), region = c('A','A','B')), 
               row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
               class = "data.frame")


mx_long2 = read.table(header = T, text = '
                      Arrears   Ars_0   Ars_1   Ars_2   Seasoning   Region
                      Ars_0 0.985   0.0148  0.0002  mths:36-47  A
                      Ars_1 0.3816  0.286   0.3317  mths:36-47  A
                      Ars_2 0.2959  0.0057  0.2524  mths:36-47  A
                      Ars_0 0.9822  0.0176  0.0002  mths:24-35  A
                      Ars_1 0.389   0.2753  0.3347  mths:24-35  A
                      Ars_2 0.3026  0.0334  0.2399  mths:24-35  A
                      Ars_0 0.9753  0.0243  0.0004  mths:12-23  A
                      Ars_1 0.4002  0.2592  0.3394  mths:12-23  A
                      Ars_2 0.3032  0.0208  0.2387  mths:12-23  A
                      Ars_0 0.8865  0.01332 0.00018 mths:36-47  B
                      Ars_1 0.34344 0.2574  0.29853 mths:36-47  B
                      Ars_2 0.26631 0.00513 0.22716 mths:36-47  B
                      Ars_0 0.88398 0.01584 0.00018 mths:24-35  B
                      Ars_1 0.3501  0.24777 0.30123 mths:24-35  B
                      Ars_2 0.27234 0.03006 0.21591 mths:24-35  B
                      Ars_0 0.87777 0.02187 0.00036 mths:12-23  B
                      Ars_1 0.36018 0.23328 0.30546 mths:12-23  B
                      Ars_2 0.27288 0.01872 0.21483 mths:12-23  B
                      ')


mx_long2 = mx_long2 %>% mutate(minage = as.numeric(substr(as.character(Seasoning), 6,7)),
                               maxage = as.numeric(substr(as.character(Seasoning), 9,10)))


x <- xx %>% select(starts_with('Ars')) %>% data.matrix()

l <- list()
p <- 1

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    Bx = filter(mx_long2, (j + xx[i, 'age']) >= minage, (j + xx[i, 'age']) <= maxage,
                Region == xx[i, 'region']) %>%
      select(starts_with('Ars_')) %>% data.matrix()

    # Matrix Multiplication
    x <-  x %*% Bx
    l[[p]] <- x
    p = p + 1
  }
  }

l
```

Comment: are you interested in a `purrr`solution?

Comment: Yes. Definitely

Comment: @john can you share snippets of the result for checking? sorry because i dont have tidyverse to run some of your codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer that joins everything and then splits::

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

xx%>%
  mutate(id_xx = seq_len(n()))%>%
  crossing(j = 1:3)%>%
  mutate(age = age + j)%>%
  inner_join(mx_long2, ., by = c('Region' = 'region'))%>%
  filter(age >= minage, age <= maxage)%>%
  arrange(j, id_xx)%>%
  select(starts_with('Ars_'))%>%
  select(ends_with('x'))%>%
  split(rep(1:9, each = 3))%>%
  lapply(function(Bx) {
    x <<- x %*% as.matrix(Bx)
    return(x)
  })
```

And similar approach with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)

x <- xx %>% select(starts_with('Ars')) %>% data.matrix()
mx_dt <- as.data.table(mx_long2)

# prepare xx for a join by expanding it by 3
j <- 3
xx_dt <- as.data.table(xx)
xx_dt <- xx_dt[rep(seq_len(nrow(xx_dt)), each = j)
               ][, `:=`(age= age + rep(seq_len(j), nrow(xx_dt)),
                        ID = .I)]

# non-equi join
BX <- mx_dt[xx_dt[, .(region, age, ID)], 
      on = .(Region = region,
             minage <= age,
             maxage >= age),
      allow.cartesian = T,
      nomatch = 0L,
      .(Ars_0, Ars_1, Ars_2, ID)]

# loop through split. 
## NOTE x <<- ... the "<<-" is a global assignment
lapply(split(BX, by = 'ID', keep.by = F),
       function(bx) {
         x <<- x %*% as.matrix(bx)
         return(x)
       }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("Ars_0","Ars_1","Ars_2")
setDT(mx_long2)[, c("minage","maxage") := 
    lapply(.(substring(Seasoning, 6, 7), substring(Seasoning, 9, 10)), as.numeric)]

xxCJ <- setDT(xx)[, .(rn=.GRP, age=c(outer(1:3, age, `+`))), c("region", cols)]

jDT <- mx_long2[xxCJ, on=.(Region=region, minage<=age, maxage>=age), nomatch=0L]

x <- as.matrix(xx[, ..cols])
jDT[, {
        mat <- matrix(unlist(mget(cols)), nrow=.N)
        x <- x %*% mat
        .(.(x))
    }, by=.(rn, age=minage)]$V1
```

output:

```
[[1]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1276.239  31.79801 0.523424
[2,] 5587.338 139.21081 2.291536
[3,] 2124.028  52.92103 0.871128

[[2]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1257.600  39.26553 11.42768
[2,] 5505.737 171.90341 50.03007
[3,] 2093.007  65.34913 19.01895

[[3]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1245.716  40.97499 16.55755
[2,] 5453.711 179.38741 72.48849
[3,] 2073.229  68.19417 27.55652

[[4]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1244.492  33.75804 17.93563
[2,] 5448.351 147.79177 78.52170
[3,] 2071.192  56.18308 29.85004

[[5]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1240.899  31.79569 15.85047
[2,] 5432.622 139.20068 69.39293
[3,] 2065.213  52.91717 26.37974

[[6]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1235.976  31.12258 14.69273
[2,] 5411.069 136.25382 64.32436
[3,] 2057.019  51.79693 24.45292

[[7]]
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1110.294  24.54953 12.85110
[2,] 4860.838 107.47716 56.26177
[3,] 1847.849  40.85747 21.38793

[[8]]
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  996.1295 21.17409 10.44788
[2,] 4361.0277 92.69960 45.74053
[3,] 1657.8458 35.23978 17.38827

[[9]]
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  893.1232 18.77225  8.873746
[2,] 3910.0690 82.18442 38.849016
[3,] 1486.4137 31.24243 14.768463
```

Comment: thanks. I need output of each iteration in list. I will add output in a while as I am away from system. Many thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go to approach for nested loops with `purrr`

```
l
x <- xx %>% select(starts_with('Ars')) %>% data.matrix()

my_list <- purrr::pmap(
  # use expand.grid() to create your iterators
  .l = expand.grid(1:nrow(x),
                   1:3),
  .f = ~{
    Bx = filter(mx_long2, (.y + xx[.x, 'age']) >= minage, (.y + xx[.x, 'age']) <= maxage,
                Region == xx[.x, 'region']) %>%
      select(starts_with('Ars_')) %>% data.matrix()

    # Matrix Multiplication
    # global assignment operator <<-
    x <<- x %*% Bx
    return(x)
  }
)
all.equal(l, my_list)
```

There are some small differences in the results between `l` and `my_list` though. I am not sure why this happens. Do I miss some random parts in the code?